# Setting environment variable with leading digit in bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell, environment-variables

I need to set an environment variable called "64bit" (i.e. with a leading digit) in bash. However, bash variable names disallow a variable with a leading digit. I know a way to set it when invoking bash:

```
env 64bit=1 /usr/bin/bash
```

However, I'm looking for a way to change it in the currently running shell i.e. not by starting a new shell. I also know that csh allows variables to start with a digit, but I need to use bash.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: Why do you *need* it? Can't you just use a different name?

Comment: csh doesn't allow variables to start with a letter; both `set` and `setenv` complain "Variable name must begin with a letter.".

Comment: The only way to set an environment variable in the current shell is through the use of `bash` shell variables, which cannot begin with a digit.

Comment: This variable is used by the configuration management team at my company, and is being read by many scripts. They use csh, but I find csh so limited when it comes to defining functions/aliases (it doesn't support functions as far as I know). So I switched to using bash with the workaround above, and I'm now trying to fix it.

Comment: From the IEEE Posix standards ... **Environment variable names used by the utilities in the Shell and Utilities volume of IEEE Std 1003.1-2001 consist solely of uppercase letters, digits, and the '_' (underscore) from the characters defined in Portable Character Set and do not begin with a digit. Other characters may be permitted by an implementation; applications shall tolerate the presence of such names.**  In other words: tell your config management guys that they're violating the standard.

Comment: @tink: "...variable names used by *the utilities in the Shell and Utilities volume of IEEE Std 1003.1-2001*..." (emphasis mine). Other programs are free to use whatever characters they like, which is why `env` is more lenient.

Comment: How do they get csh to permit variables names to start with a digit?

Comment: I can set an environment variable called 64bit in csh. setenv accepts it. I can't read it back using echo $64bit though, but env | grep 64bit shows it's set.

Comment: Interesting. BSD csh allows `setenv 64bit 1`, but tcsh doesn't.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can also bypass the bash interpreter and define the variable directly with the bash internal functions:

```
$ gdb --batch-silent -ex "attach $$"                              \
    -ex 'set bind_variable("64bit", "1", 0)'                      \
    -ex 'set *(int*)(find_variable("64bit")+sizeof(char*)*5) = 1' \
    -ex 'set array_needs_making = 1'

$ env | grep 64
64bit=1
```

Comment: +1 for being the craziest / cleverest use of gdb I've come across in years.

Answer (score 1):

As people point out, Bash does not allow variables starting with digits. It does however pass on unrecognized environment string to external programs, which is why the variable shows up in `env` but not in `set`.

As a workaround, you can work with a valid name like `_64bit` and then automatically inject your invalid variable name into commands you run:

```
#!/bin/bash    
# Setup for injection hack
original=$PATH
PATH="/"
command_not_found_handle() {
  PATH="$original" env "64bit=$_64bit" "$@"
}

# Your script and logic
_64bit="some dynamic value"

# This verifies that '64bit' is automatically set
env | grep ^64bit
```

Note that this particular method only works if you invoke through $PATH, not if you use relative or absolute path names.

If you do invoke by pathname, consider modifying PATH and invoking by name instead.