# Modify a variable in a running Bash script

Tags: bash, gdb

I have a bash script which processes several years of data, therefore the script can take a week to finish.
To speed up the process, I use multithreading, by running several instances in parallel (each instance = 1 day of data). Each instance occupies 1 CPU, so I can run as many instances as CPUs available. As I am running the process in a powerful server which I am sharing with others, at some time I may have more or less CPUs available.
My current script is:

```
#!/bin/bash
function waitpid {
   #Gather the gLABs PID background processes (Maximum processes in 
   #background as number of CPUs)
   NUMPIDS=`jobs -p|awk 'END {print NR}'`
   #A while is set because there seems to be a bug in bash that makes 
   #sometimes the "wait -n" command
   #exit even if none of provided PIDs have finished. If this happens, 
   #the while loops forces the 
   #script to wait until one of the processes is truly finished
   while [ ${NUMPIDS} -ge ${NUMCPUS} ]
   do
     #Wait for gLAB processes to finish
     PIDS="`jobs -p|awk -v ORS=" " '{print}'`"
     wait -n ${PIDS} >/dev/null 2>/dev/null
     NUMPIDS=`jobs -p|awk 'END {print NR}'`
   done
}
NUMPCUS=10
for(...) #Loop for each day
do
   day=... #Set current day variable
   #Command to execute, put in background
   gLAB_linux -input ${day}folder/${day}.input -output ${day)outfolder/${day}.output &        
   #Wait for any process to finish if NUMCPUS number of processes are running in background
   waitpid 
done
```

Therefore, my question is: if this script is running, is there any way I can change the variable NUMCPUS to any value (for instance NUMCPUS=23) without stopping the script?.
If possible, I would prefer a method that does not involve reading or writing to file (I like to reduce temporary files to 0 if possible). 
I don't mind if it is a "hackish" process, such as the method described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15508327/setting-environment-variable-with-leading-digit-in-bash). Actually, I tried in gdb similar commands as in that answer but it didn't work, I had the following errors in gdb (and also made the process to crash):

```
(gdb) attach 23865
(gdb) call bind_variable("NUMCPUS",11,0)
'bind_variable' has unknown return type; cast the call to its declared return type
(gdb) call (int)bind_variable("NUMCPUS",11,0)
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault
```

EDIT1: Some comments to the script:

- gLAB_linux is a single core processing program and is not aware of NUMCPUS variable
- Each gLAB_linux execution takes around 5 hours to finish, therefore the bash script is most of the time sleeping inside the `wait -n`.
- NUMCPUS must be a local variable for the script, as there may be another script like this one running in parallel (changing only the parameters given to gLAB_linux). Therefore NUMCPUS can't be an environment variable.
- The only process accessing NUMCPUS is the bash script

EDIT2: After @Kamil answer, I add my proposal for reading from a file the number of CPUs

```
function waitpid {
   #Look if there is a file with new number of CPUs
   if [ -s "/tmp/numCPUs_$$.txt" ]
   then
     TMPVAR=$(awk '$1>0 {print "%d",$1} {exit}' "/tmp/numCPUs_$$.txt")
     if [ -n "${TMPVAR}" ]
     then
       NUMCPUS=${TMPVAR}
       echo "NUMCPUS=${TMPVAR}"
     fi
     rm -f "/tmp/numCPUs_$$.txt"
   fi

   #Gather the gLABs PID background processes (Maximum processes in 
   #background as number of CPUs)
   NUMPIDS=`jobs -p|awk 'END {print NR}'`
   #A while is set because there seems to be a bug in bash that makes 
   #sometimes the "wait -n" command
   #exit even if none of provided PIDs have finished. If this happens, 
   #the while loops forces the 
   #script to wait until one of the processes is truly finished
   while [ ${NUMPIDS} -ge ${NUMCPUS} ]
   do
     #Wait for gLAB processes to finish
     PIDS="`jobs -p|awk -v ORS=" " '{print}'`"
     wait -n ${PIDS} >/dev/null 2>/dev/null
     NUMPIDS=`jobs -p|awk 'END {print NR}'`
   done
}
```

Comment: See the `--limit` argument of [GNU parallel](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/man.html).

Comment: what about control with signal?

Comment: Each instance will have different input and output files and folder, so I can't use parallel bash command. I edited the question. With signals, the problem is that I can't set an arbitrary value to the variable

Comment: @AwkMan read the variable from a file is much more reliable than hack with gdb, but I guess you are doing this for fun, than good luck! btw `parallel` could read cmd lines from stdin.

Comment: Regarding the `wait -n` "bug": `wait -n` waits for the next background job to finish; *next* as in *next of all background jobs of the current session*. The PIDs specified after `-n` are ignored. You can verify this with `sleep 1 & sleep 9 & wait -n $!`. `$!` is the PID of `sleep 9`, but `wait` will only wait for `sleep 1`.

Comment: @Socowi The bug I mention is than wait returns before any of the processes has finished. As the only processes of this session are the gLAB_linux processes in the background, wait should return only when any gLAB_linux had finished. But I saw that I had more than NUMCPUs gLAB_linux running (and every time more and more) if I didn't add the while

Comment: @georgexsh Yes, I would like a gdb hack because its fun, and changing the variable is something I rarely need to do. About parallel, even I use it, I still have the same problem, how do I change the number of CPUs dinamically at any point of the execution?

Comment: @AwkMan parallel supports read proc num from a file.

Answer (score 2):

The best would be to modify the bash script so it is aware that you change the value. Modifying an environment variable from inside a gdb session - that's just intrusive and mostly discards other developers work.

Below I use a file named `/tmp/signal_num_cpus`. If the file doesn't exist, the script uses the NUMCPUS value. If the file does exists, it reads it content and updates the number of NUMCPUS accordingly and then prints some notification that the numcpus was changed to the file. If the file does exists and does not contain a valid number (for example in predefined range or smth) it prints some error message into the file. The other side is notified that everything is ok or something bad happened

```
#!/bin/bash

is_not_number() { 
    (( $1 != $1 )) 2>/dev/null
}

# global variable to hold the number of cpus with a default value
NUMCPUS=${NUMCPUS:=5}
# this will ideally execute on each access to NUMCPUS variable
# depending on content
get_num_cpus() { 
   # I tell others that NUMCPUS is a global variable and i expect it here
   declare -g NUMCPUS
   # I will use this filename to communicate
   declare -r file="/tmp/signal_num_cpus"
   # If the file exists and is a fifo...
   if [ -p "$file" ]; then
       local tmp
       # get file contents
       tmp=$(<"$file")
       if [ -z "$tmp" ]; then
           #empty is ignored
           :;
       elif is_not_number "$tmp"; then
           echo "Error reading a number from $file" >&2
           echo "error: not a number, please give me a number!" > "$file"
       else
           # If it is ok, update the NUMCPUS value
           NUMCPUS=$tmp
           echo "ok $NUMCPUS" > "$file"  # this will block until other side starts reading
       fi
   fi
   # last but not least, let's output it
   echo "$NUMCPUS"
}

# code duplication is the worst (ok, sometimes except for databases frameworks)
get_num_bg_jobs() {
    jobs -p | wc -l
}

waitpid() {
   while 
         (( $(get_num_bg_jobs) >= $(get_num_cpus) ))
   do
         wait -n
   done
}

# rest of the script

NUMPCUS=10
for(...) #Loop for each day
do
   day=... #Set current day variable
   #Command to execute, put in background
   gLAB_linux -input "${day}folder/${day}.input" -output "${day)outfolder/${day}.output" &        
   #Wait for any process to finish if NUMCPUS number of processes are running in background
   waitpid 
done
```

And changing the value script could look like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

# shared context between scripts
declare -r file="/tmp/signal_num_cpus"

mkfifo "$file"

echo 1 > "$file" # this will block until other side will start reading

IFS= read -r line < "$file"

case "$line" in
ok*) 
     read _ numcpus <<<"$line"
     echo "the script changed the number of numcpus to $numcpus"
     ;;
*)
     echo "the script errored with $error"
     ;;
esac

rm "$file"
```

Marks:

- the correct way to define a function is `func() { :; }` Using `function func { }` is somthing taken from ksh and is supported as an extension. Use `func() {}`
- It is nice to use arithmetic expansion `(( ... ))` for number comparisons nad handling.
- Using backticks ` for command substitution `$( ... )` is deprecated.

Comment: Your method for using a file I find it way too complicated, specially regardind the use of "declare" and mkfifo. Maybe because I forgot to clarify some things in my questions (see edit in my question). I will edit (again) my question for adding my proposal

Comment: `declare` is just there to simplify reading, you can toss them all out. `mkfifo` is used because it's easier to synchronize processes using them, you can use normal file + `flock` or disregard locking altogether. If you search for multiple instances of the script to run, append unique name to the config-filename in each script, for example by using `$$`.

Answer (score 1):

Chapter 7.1 of GNU Parallel 2018 covers how to change the number of threads to use while running https://zenodo.org/record/1146014

```
echo 50% > my_jobs
/usr/bin/time parallel -N0 --jobs my_jobs sleep 1 :::: num128 &
sleep 1
echo 0 > my_jobs
wait
```

So you simply put the argument for `--jobs` into `my_jobs` and GNU Parallel will read this after each completed job.